# error after clientCredentialType="Certificate"

Tags: azure, wcf, ssl

After enable of

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

from

```
<transport clientCredentialType="None" />
```

I'm getting the error shown here while accessing the REST service.

The exception message is:

> The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'None'
>
> System.NotSupportedException: The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'None'.

Comment: after change to  <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />. Earlier it was clientCredentialType="None" in web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

After changing clientCredentialType to Certificate, the WCF service needs to accept the client's certificate. If WCF is deployed in IIS, the certificate will be ignored by default, which requires you to enable.

[image]

[image]

Choose to accept client certificate.

**UPDATE**

This may be caused by the web app ignoring the client's certificate. You can configure the web app in Azure to accept the certificate from the client:

[image]

For more details you can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth

Comment: Looking how to configured above setting on Azure Web Apps since above changes to Azure web apps.